# Hmisc: How do I include the results of reformM as an argument in aregImpute?

Tags: r, hmisc

I am using `aregImpute` from the `Hmisc` package to impute missing values in a dataset. Since the results are not invariant to the order of variables in the formula, I have used the `reformM` function to generate a number of random formula permutations:

`reformM(~ x1 + x2 + x3..., data = d, nperm = Z)`

The function returns a list.

I have reviewed the help file, but am unclear on how the results can be passed to `aregImpute`.

Can the object be passed such that `aregImpute` will iterate over the different combinations to assess any variability? That is, can the more than one permutation be passed to `aregImpute`? If not, do I simply create a new formula using the new order of variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use `map` to pass `reformM` to `aregImpute`. Below, I provide a minimal example. That said, I do think it is a better idea to reorder variables such that variables with higher missing data rates are first imputed.

```
library(missForest)
library(tidyverse)
iris_miss <- prodNA(iris,0.10)  ## make every variable missing at 10% 
## factorial(ncol(iris_miss))  ## number of possible permutations
permlist <- reformM( as.formula(paste(" ~ ", names(iris_miss) %>% str_flatten( " + "))), data=iris_miss, nperm=10 ) ## get 10 permutations 
map(permlist, aregImpute, nk=3, n.impute=5, data= iris_miss)
```